# Julia - Equivalent of Python lmfit

Tags: python, julia, least-squares, lmfit

I would like to minimize `x` and `y` in function `f` using least square (Levenberg-Marquardt). In Python I can use `lmfit` like follows

```py
params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('x', value=0, min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
params.add('y', value=0.0, min=-0.25, max=0.25)
# Least square is the default method
x,y = lmfit.minimize(f, params)
```

Is there any equivalent/what is the best way to achieve this in Julia?

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be Levenberg-Marquardt? If not, you can get what you want using [Optim.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl):

```
using Optim

f(x) = x[1]^2 + x[2]^4
result = optimize(f, [1.0,2.0]) # minimum expected at (0,0)
x,y = result.minimizer # (2.3024075561537708e-5, -0.0009216015268974243)

lbounds = [1, -0.25]
ubounds = [2, 0.25]
result = optimize(f, lbounds, ubounds, [1.5,0.1]) # minimum expected at (1,0)
x,y = result.minimizer # (1.0000000000000002, -2.1978466115000986e-11)
```

**Previous answer:**

You could perhaps use the package [LsqFit.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl):

```
using LsqFit

# function with two parameters
@. f(x, p) = p[1]*exp(-x*p[2])

# fake data
xdata = range(0, stop=10, length=20)
ydata = f(xdata, [1.0 2.0]) + 0.01*randn(length(xdata))

# upper and lower bounds + initial parameter guess
lb = [-π, -0.25]
ub = [π, 0.25]
p0 = [0.5, 0.1]

# least squares fit
fit_bounds = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, lower=lb, upper=ub)
p1,p2 = fit_bounds.param
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to pass in another argument to `f` (this will be `Vector`) in `optimize` that is not to be minimized (constant `Vector`)?

Comment: Also, can function `f` returns an `Array`? [This](https://github.com/openmrslab/suspect/blob/master/suspect/processing/phase.py#L38) is the python function that I tried to implement in Julia and they seem to be able to minimize a numpy array.

Comment: Yes, you can pass extra arguments to `f`. You can use a closure for this, `x->f(x,a)`, where `a` is an additional vector to be passed to f.

Comment: As to your second question, the function `residual` also returns a scalar, AFAICS.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! Anyway, pretty sure the `residual` in that function returns array, since `frequency_slice` is a [`slice`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice) object. Can I also get this working for array in Julia?